# Redirect to an IP while masking the URL

Tags: redirects, ip-address, iis, node-js

Using a Node.JS web server, I want to have an IIS setup to where the user goes to 
`bot.url.co/dashboard` it sends the data to `ip:port/dashboard`, where IP:port is handled using Node.JS, but the link doesn't change before the `/`. Is this doable?

Comment: Just doing a redirect works, but I don't want to show the IP. And since its a Node.JS server, it would be nice if I can just "hook" into that, if possible Using Windows Server 2012 R2

Answer (score 1):

You need to set-up a reverse proxy in IIS that redirects the requests to your Node.js Server and serves back the response to your users. This is as easy as 1.2.3 in IIS using the URL Rewriter module.

Here you have an explanation:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/

Comment: "inverse proxy" - presume you mean a "reverse" proxy?

Comment: Well, yes... Fixed.